# Django serializer validate related serializer

Tags: python, django

I have two Django Model, one depend on another. I made serializers for them, but I don't understand how i'm supposed to link the serializer so one call the validation of the child.

```
class Tree(Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)

class Leaf(Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    tree= ForeignKey(Tree, on_delete=SET_NULL, db_column="etude")
```

My serializers look like this

```
class TreeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    leafList = LeafSerializer(source="leaf_set", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tree
        fields = [
            "id",
            "leafList",
        ]
    def create(self, validated_data):
        leafs = validated_data.pop("leaf_set", [])
        instance = Tree.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for leaf in leafs :
            leaf.update({"tree": instance})
            Leaf.objects.create(**leaf)

class LeafSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Leaf
        fields = [
            "id",
            "tree"
        ]

        def validate(self, attrs):
            return False
```

But my `LeafSerializer` seems to never be called. All objects are properly created, but LeafSerializer's `validate` method is never run, thus don't prevent creation when a Leaf is invalid. I can't find in the [django rest documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) instructions on how to do validation on related object. I've looked at [django rest relations documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) but i'm not sure it is what i'm looking for.

I'm thinking about explicitly creating a LeafSerializer inside the `create` function of TreeSerializer. I would be able to check the data, but i'm not sure if that's the right way to do it (and probably not the right place, doing it inside the validate function of TreeSerializer is probably "less worse")

Comment: Try adding `write_only=True` and `read_only=True` to the `leafList` field of your `TreeSerializer`.

Comment: Both can't be set simultaniously. With read_only, my objects aren't created but the leaf validator isn't check. With write_only, nothing seems to change